# Telephony event notification in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, telephony, tapi

I have a Windows Forms application, developed in C#, that would benefit from being able to receive telephony event notifications.

For example, if office worker Joe answers a telephone call on his organization's PBX system, I need my desktop application to know it (as well as when he initiates a call, when he hangs up, etc.).

I would like to use as generic and common a mechanism as possible to achieve this goal for maximum hardware / telephony system support.

Any advice regarding what mix of technologies are best applicable would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a TAPI OCX control onto your form to receive the telephony events.  There are several free and shareware TAPI controls available on the internet.  TAPI supports both traditional and VOIP telephony, all you need is for your telephony equipment vendor to provide a TSP that supports their equipment.

Also see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748186/how-to-capture-a-phone-number/762688#762688).